# pandas isin() function with lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to 2 data frames and I want to use

> isin() method

to check what exists in df1 and also in df2.

When I compare only one column (index1) - the result is ok - 2 values of df1.index1 exists in df2.index1.

but when I compare 2 columns (index1, index2) of both df1 and df2 the result is false for all the 3 rows, even that there is one common row (index1 = 3, index2 = 6).

Why is that?

Thanks.

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'index1':[1,2,3], 'index2':[4,5,6]})
In [4]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4,5,6], 'index1':[2,3,4], 'index2':[7,6,5]})


In [5]: df1
Out[5]:    
   A  index1  index2
0  1       1       4
1  2       2       5
2  3       3       6

In [6]: df2
Out[6]:    
   A  index1  index2
0  4       2       7
1  5       3       6
2  6       4       5

In [7]: df1['index1'].isin(df2['index1'])
Out[7]: 
0     False
1     True
2     True
Name: index1, dtype: bool

In [8]: df1['index2'].isin(df2['index2'])
Out[8]: 
0     False
1     True
2     True
Name: index2, dtype: bool

In [9]: df1[['index1','index2']].isin(df2[['index1', 'index2']])
Out[9]:   
   index1 index2
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
```